# How do I install a custom recovery on a Note 3 from OS X?

Tags: recovery-mode, heimdall

I have a Note 3. I want to install CyanogenMod on it, so I will need a custom recovery. My computer is OS X.

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_hlte says:

> If you've applied the 4.4.x update to your hlte device, it is possible heimdall will have communication issues with your device. This is a filed bug already on the heimdall page and this warning will be removed when it is resolved. In the meantime, ODIN still works.

My Note 3 has had 4.4.x ever since I got it. I tried to use heimdall, but it fails as the warning suggests. It's [this issue](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/209).

Is there any alternative to heimdall on OS X for installing a custom recovery?

Answer (score 0):

All I know is to use Odin on windows. If heimdall doesn't work, you will have no chance from osx.

But there might be one solution:
Unpack your umage until you have a recovery.img file. Put it on your rooted device.
In the device shell as root type if=/pathtorecoverymimg of=/dev/block/platform/,,,,,/by-name/recovery
Sync,  reboot

To do a backup of the partition first is always a good idea. Just do it the other way round to get a backup in a file.

Some devices automatically restore recovery on boot. Try to reboot directly into recovery ( eventually disable automated recovery recovery using cwm recovery :)